# easygui fileopenbox: open a path with a '.' (ex C:\Users\user\.atom)

Tags: python, path, easygui

I would like to open a file dialog with easygui but the path contains a folder with a `.`: `C:\Users\user\.atom`

```
myfile= easygui.fileopenbox(msg="Choose a file", default=r"C:\Users\user\.atom")
```

This opens the dialog box to `C:\Users\user` not `C:\Users\user\.atom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't / don't use *easygui*, just looked at the source code.

*easygui* does some path processing on the `default` argument. That processing involves [[Python]: os.path.**split**(*path*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) which splits the path in 2 parts (what comes before and after the last path separator (*bkslash* or "*\*")). 
Since "*.atom*" comes after the last "*\*", it's not considered as part of the path (the fact that it contains a "*.*" is just a coincidence and has nothing to do with it).

To fix your problem, add a wildcard to your path, e.g.:

```
myfile = easygui.fileopenbox(msg="Choose a file", default=r"C:\Users\user\.atom\*")
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion between  ".credentials" and ".atom", it was  really ".atom". Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!

Comment: No worries, it's not like it was creating a confusion. It's the same principle no matter what the dir name would be.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to end default with two `\\`:

```
r"C:\Users\user\.atom\\"
```